# What ist the fontspec equivalent for "variable=true"

Tags: fontspec, lmodern

With pdflatex, I used the `cfr-lm` package with following settings:

```
\usepackage[%
  rm={oldstyle=false,proportional=true},%
  sf={oldstyle=false,proportional=true},%
  tt={oldstyle=false,proportional=true,variable=true},%
  qt=false%
]{cfr-lm}
```

When using lualatex, I am using the following one

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
```

Now, each letter of the monospaced font has the same width. However, I like the `variable=true` feature. How can I active it at `setmonofont`?

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! LaTeX error: "kernel/key-unknown"
!
! The key 'fontspec-opentype/Variable' is unknown and is being ignored.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by the table on page 8 of the `cfr-lm` documentation, what you’re looking for is Latin Modern Mono Prop, a set of fonts, not a feature of the better known Latin Modern Mono fonts. So you can use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono Prop}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\begin{document}
\texttt{This is Latin Modern Mono Prop, a proportional typewriter font.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]